# Android Xamarin RendererFactory.getRenderer() does not work

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

For Data Template I have used `StackLayout` with label inside it and created a **custom renderer** for `grid-view`.

The code `RendererFactory.getRenderer()` doesn't work; it only shows a `StackLayout` without any label inside.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As of now `RendererFactory.getRenderer()` won't work for auto layout containers such as StackLayout/GridLayout with child contents [refer this link](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/33092/rendererfactory-getrenderer-is-it-bug-child-content). Only the primary parent is rendered but the childrens are not rendered in UI but the controls are available after converting to native view 
`this._view = RendererFactory.GetRenderer(this._viewCell.View).NativeView;`

Try using **`AbsoluteLayout`** and position the controls accordingly. I had tried this using [XLabs Grid View Control](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/GridView.cs) since they used Grid View Renderer for making the UICollectionView(TileList) and [GridViewCell](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/GridView/GridViewCell.cs) for generating the viewCell from Forms to Native.

```
<controls:GridView
                    x:Name="GrdView"
                    RowSpacing="5"
                    Padding="5"
                    ColumnSpacing = "5"
                    ItemWidth ="152"
                    ItemHeight = "200"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding gridColl}"
                >
            <controls:GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                         <!-- WORKING-->
                            <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Red">

                                <Image Source="{Binding image}"  
                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 0.5, 0.5"
                                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
                                <BoxView Color="#8080FF"
                                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.33, 0, 0.25, 0.25"
                                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
                                <Label Text="Test" BackgroundColor="Red"
                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 1, 0.5, 0.5"
                                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"/>
                            </AbsoluteLayout>

                             <!--NOT WORKING-->
                            <!--<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Blue">
                                <Image Source="{Binding image}" />
                                <Label Text="Test" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
                            </StackLayout>-->
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:GridView>
```

i hope this might help you...